# Вытаскиваем нужное значение из функции в классе

Tags: php, ооп, функции

Добрый день! Есть большой ООП класс: `$db`. 
В нем есть функция:

```
public function paginate ($table, $page, $fields = null){
  $offset = $this->pageLimit * ($page - 1);
  $res = $this->withTotalCount()->get ($table, Array ($offset, $this->pageLimit), $fields);
  $this->totalPages = ceil($this->totalCount / $this->pageLimit);
  return $res;
}
```

1. Я получаю значение из этой функции `$clients=$db->paginate('clients', 1);`
2. Но при этом надо параллельно вытащить из нее же значение `totalPages`. Как это сделать?

Comment: $pages=$db->totalPages

Comment: Не получится так. Он в самом начале класса задан как public $totalPages = 0;  Надо вытащить его значение именно из этой функции.

Comment: После выполнения pagination переменная примет другое значение и не будет изменяться до следующего вызова pagination

Comment: Пробовал. не выводит данные.

Comment: Возможно, она объявлена как private или protected? Выведет только public.

Comment: Да, нет, она public. Но в принципе ответ был найден ниже в виде массива! Хотя Ваш ответ мне больше понравился! Спасибо за посильную помощь! :-)

Comment: В виде массива правильнее :) Не забудьте принять верный ответ

Answer (score 1):

Можно возвращать массив:

```
public function paginate ($table, $page, $fields = null){
        $offset = $this->pageLimit * ($page - 1);
        $res = $this->withTotalCount()->get ($table, Array ($offset, $this->pageLimit), $fields);
        $this->totalPages = ceil($this->totalCount / $this->pageLimit);
        return [
            "res" => $res,
            "total_pages" => $this->totalPages
        ];
}
```

Получение:

```
$clients = $db->paginate('clients', 1);
$res = $clients['res'];
$count = $clients['count];
```

Можно возвращать кол-во по ссылке:

```
public function paginate ($table, $page, $fields = null, &$count){
        $offset = $this->pageLimit * ($page - 1);
        $res = $this->withTotalCount()->get ($table, Array ($offset, $this->pageLimit), $fields);
        $this->totalPages = ceil($this->totalCount / $this->pageLimit);
        return $res;
}
```

Получение:

```
$count = 0;
$clients = $db->paginate('clients', 1, null, $count);
```

Comment: Хорошее предложение насчет массива! Вот только реализация не получается! `public function paginate ($table, $page, $fields = null){
        $offset = $this->pageLimit * ($page - 1);
        $res = $this->withTotalCount()->get ($table, Array ($offset, $this->pageLimit), $fields);
        $df = $this->totalPages = ceil($this->totalCount / $this->pageLimit);
            return [
            "res" => $res,
            "last" => $df ];
    }` Может массив надо как-то по другому написать?

Comment: Какая версия `php`? попробуйте заменить на `return array("res" => $res, "last" => $df);`

Answer (score 0):

- Все, заработал массив! В старом и новом виде он работает.
- Просто мои запросы оказывается нельзя было объединять, т.к. между ними идут
  вычисления.
- Спасибо за помощь!

  > public function paginate ($table, $page, $fields = null){
  >           $offset = $this->pageLimit * ($page - 1);
  >           $res = $this->withTotalCount()->get ($table, Array ($offset, $this->pageLimit), $fields);
  >           $dg = $this->totalPages = ceil($this->totalCount / $this->pageLimit);
  >           return [
  >                     "res" => $res,
  >                     "last" => $dg
  >                 ];
  >       }
  >
  > $res = $db->paginate('clients', $pagenum); $last = $res['last'];
  >
  > $res = $db->paginate('clients', $pagenum); $clients = $res['res'];